# SQL expression problem

Tags: sql, group-by, expression

Below is my table, a User could have multiple profiles in certain languages, non-English profiles have a higher priority.

```
+----------+--------+----------------+----------------+
|ProfileID |UserID  |ProfileLanguage |ProfilePriority |
+----------+--------+----------------+----------------+
|1         |1       |en-US           |2               |
+----------+--------+----------------+----------------+
|2         |1       |es-MX           |1               |
+----------+--------+----------------+----------------+
|3         |1       |ja-JP           |1               |
+----------+--------+----------------+----------------+
|4         |2       |es-MX           |1               |
+----------+--------+----------------+----------------+
|5         |2       |ja-JP           |2               |
+----------+--------+----------------+----------------+
|6         |2       |de-DE           |1               |
+----------+--------+----------------+----------------+
|7         |3       |en-US           |2               |
+----------+--------+----------------+----------------+
```

For example: When a Spanish-speaking visitor requests my site (where ProfileLanguage = 'es-MX' or ProfilePriority = 2), I want the records like below:

```
+----------+--------+----------------+----------------+
|ProfileID |UserID  |ProfileLanguage |ProfilePriority |
+----------+--------+----------------+----------------+
|2         |1       |es-MX           |1               |
+----------+--------+----------------+----------------+
|5         |2       |ja-JP           |2               |
+----------+--------+----------------+----------------+
|7         |3       |en-US           |2               |
+----------+--------+----------------+----------------+
```

Below, is the basic SQL to get the users:

```
SELECT UserID, MIN(ProfilePriority) AS ProfilePriority
FROM Profile
WHERE ProfileLanguage = 'es-MX' OR ProfilePriority = 2
GROUP BY UserID
```

But as you know, I can only get the UserID, but I also need other column information, like ProfileID etc.. So I hope experts here could tell me the correct SQL expression to get the right records.

Comment: In your result table, your first record with PROFILE_ID = 2, is not qualifying given condition, I believe.

Comment: To Adiel A.: Sorry, that was a writing mistake, I just corrected it, the condition should be "where ProfileLanguage = 'es-MX' or ProfilePriority = 2"

Comment: One more place to correct it.. . . Guess where. . .. In your query ;)

Comment: Sorry again, It has been corrected. Thanks for reminding me ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may work, if profilepriority and userid could be a composite unique key;

```
select p.* from Profile p join 
(SELECT UserID, MIN(ProfilePriority) AS ProfilePriority
FROM Profile
WHERE ProfileLanguage = 'en-US' OR ProfilePriority = 2
GROUP BY UserID) tt
on p.userID = tt.UserID and p.ProfilePriority = tt.ProfilePriority
```

Comment: @todownvoteman: Could you please explain why down vote was given and let me to learn the correct answer?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it didn't work as I expected, it still returns multiple UserIDs.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM Profile as tb1 inner join
(SELECT UserID, MIN(ProfilePriority) AS ProfilePriority
FROM Profile
WHERE ProfileLanguage = 'es-MX' OR ProfilePriority = 2
GROUP BY UserID) as tb2 on 
tb1.userid = tb2.userid and tb1.ProfilePriority = tb2.ProfilePriority
```

Enter all the columns you require in separated with a comma instead of * in the above query.

Comment: Who deleted my comment instead of giving an answer?

Comment: To Smiksha, I tried, but it doesn't work, it still returns a result with multiple items with the same UserID.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me, though it is not clear without your table and maybe some sample data, that your problem is solved by just extending your grouping as follows:

```
SELECT UserID, ProfileID, MIN(ProfilePriority) AS ProfilePriority
FROM Profile
WHERE ProfileLanguage = 'en-US' OR ProfilePriority = 2
GROUP BY UserID, ProfileID
```

Comment: May get two records with same USER_ID, but different PROFILE_ID. I hope you got the point.

Comment: Yes, I got multiple UserIDs, I want the result only returns the unique UserID.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have a priority if profilepriority and profilelanguage both are correct. So  this may help in that case;

```
select p.* from
(select tt1.userid, min(tt.pr) pr from 
(
SELECT profileid, UserID, MIN(ProfilePriority) AS ProfilePriority, 1 as pr
FROM Profile
WHERE ProfileLanguage = 'en-US' and ProfilePriority = 2
GROUP BY profileid, UserID

union 

SELECT profileid, UserID, MIN(ProfilePriority) AS ProfilePriority, 2 as pr
FROM Profile
WHERE ProfileLanguage = 'en-US' or ProfilePriority = 2
GROUP BY profileid, UserID

) tt1
group by userid) tt2    
join
(
SELECT profileid, UserID, MIN(ProfilePriority) AS ProfilePriority, 1 as pr
FROM Profile
WHERE ProfileLanguage = 'en-US' and ProfilePriority = 2
GROUP BY profileid, UserID

union 

SELECT profileid, UserID, MIN(ProfilePriority) AS ProfilePriority, 2 as pr
FROM Profile
WHERE ProfileLanguage = 'en-US' or ProfilePriority = 2
GROUP BY profileid, UserID
) tt3
on tt2.userId = tt3.userId and tt2.pr = tt3.pr
join profile p on p.profileid = tt3.profileid
```